# onZoom not triggered when zooming

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have made a line chart using react-chartjs-2 with a plugin called chartjs-plugin-zoom. I want to display the zoom level in console when zooming the chart. However, the onZoom seems not being triggered or called when zooming as I can't see any updates in the console panel. Would like to ask whether my syntax for onZoom is wrong and how can I fix that?

**online example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-frost-m6fuz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you putted the `onZoom` callback in the wrong place in the options object. You putted it at the root of the zoom plugin config while it has to be configured in the zoom part so in this namespace: `options.plugins.zoom.zoom.onZoom`

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-forest-9mtii?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you that works for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the onZoom in the wrong nested object.
If u place the onZoom function inside the plugins-zoom-zoom object it will work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-river-zry93?file=/src/App.js:3038-3538

```
plugins: {
              zoom: {
                zoom: {
                  wheel: {
                    enabled: true
                  },
                  mode: "x",
                  onZoom: function ({ chart }) {
                    console.log(`I'm zooming!!!`);
                  },
                  // Function called once zooming is completed
                  onZoomComplete: function ({ chart }) {
                    console.log(`I was zoomed!!!`);
                  }
                },
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue.